# World of Warcraft Addon Assistance

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I am trying to create an addon for WoW and I have UI window created that has an inputbox and an add button. I want someone to be able to type a number into that box, hit add and the number with a blank inputbox to the right of the number appear in the window below in a list. I can get the add button to add the number to a savedvariable on logout, but I can't get it to display in the window. Any help would be greatly appreciated! This is the code I have so far for the add button.

```
    PIConfig.addBtn = CreateFrame("Button", nil, PIConfig,   "GameMenuButtonTemplate");
    PIConfig.addBtn:SetPoint("Center", PIConfig, "Center", 40, 50);
    PIConfig.addBtn:SetSize(80, 30);
    PIConfig.addBtn:SetText("Add");
    PIConfig.addBtn:SetNormalFontObject("GameFontNormal");
    PIConfig.addBtn:SetHighlightFontObject("GameFontHighlight");
    PIConfig.addBtn:SetScript("OnClick", function(self, button, down)         
    if InputBox10 ~= "" then
       itemNum = InputBox10:GetNumber()           
    end        

    table.insert(perList, itemNum)

    for i,v in ipairs(perList) do
        PerItList[v] = {
            ["itemName"] = GetItemInfo(v),
            ["num1"] = 0,
            ["num2"] = 0
        }
    end
end)
```